# Textview quando clicar , aumentar certo valor que esteja no edit text

Tags: android

Estou fazendo um aplicativo de teste que possui 1 edit e um textview , o edit text vai possuir um valor dentro de inicial 0 , quando clicar no textview , quero que aumente para 10,00 , e se clicar denovo aumente para 20 , e assim sucessivamente

```
        teste = findViewById(R.id.add10);
        teste2 = findViewById(R.id.editText);

        teste.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int a=Integer.parseInt(teste2.getText().toString());
                int b=a+10;
                teste2.setText(new Integer(b).toString());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Segue logcat

```
01-22 10:23:48.987 8645-8645/com.example.gabriel.teste E/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.qualcomm.qti.Performance" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
01-22 10:23:49.100 8645-8645/com.example.gabriel.teste E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.example.gabriel.teste, PID: 8645
 java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Name"
     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:521)
     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:556)
     at com.example.gabriel.teste.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:25)
     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6261)
     at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11159)
     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23748)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

Comment: Não deu certo é um pouco vago. Não correu ? Deu erro ? Não fez nada ? Não somou o valor que era suposto ? Tente ser um pouco mais especifico no problema que tem.

Comment: Seja mais específico no erro que ocorreu, e passe maiores informações para nos ajudar a te ajudar.

Comment: Galera , coloquei o logcat na pergunta

Comment: Qual valor você está passando no textview e no edittext?

Comment: @AntonioS.Junior 10

Comment: Esse erro acontece quando tu passa algum valor null ou que o parse não consegue converter. Me parece que tu tem alguma string "Name" no teu app e ele tá tentando converter pra Integer.

Comment: @AntonioS.Junior obrigado , o erro era porque no edit tinha o valor de name , consegui resolver

Comment: boa! Vou só adicionar como resposta pra servir pra outras pessoas que tiverem o mesmo problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse erro acontece quando tu passa algum valor "null" ou que o parse não consegue converter. Me parece que tu tem alguma string "Name" no teu app e ele tá tentando converter pra Integer.

Uma boa prática quando realizamos cast é sempre verificar se o valor pode retornar nulo ou em algum formato que o tipo não consiga converter.

Answer (score 2):

Amigo,
Primeiro de tudo defina no seu textview que ele deve aceitar apenas numeros:

```
android:inputType="number"
```

Depois, é só colocar um setOnClickListener para incrementar o value:

```
tvAdd10 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.add10);
tvValorAtual = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

tvAdd10.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view){
    int valorAtual = Integer.parseInt(tvValorAtual.getText().toString());
    int novoValor = valorAtual + 10;
    tvValorAtual.setText(String.valueOf(novoValor));
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    teste = findViewById(R.id.add10);
        teste2 = findViewById(R.id.editText);

        teste.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int a=Integer.parseInt(teste2.getText().toString());
                int b=a+10;
                teste2.setText(String.valueOf(b));
            }
        });
```

Comment: Não esqueça de colocar 0 caso o edittex esteja vazia